# How do I assign a new array to each key value in another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, str-replace

Array 1:

```
$data = array(

'@attributes' => array(
    'coolid' => 'V546546',
    'emailaddress' => 'member@gmail.com',
    ));
```

This is array 2:

```
$map = array(

'foo' => array(
    'id' => 'foo',
    'tag' => '{my:foo}', 
    'label' => __( 'Foo', 'my_plugin' ),
    'callback' => 'foo'
  ));
```

I am trying to create a new array for each key in $data['@attributes']. I am trying to get the new array to have the same structure as $map but replace mentions of 'foo' with the the $keys $data['@attributes']... Such that the following outputs:

```
$desiredArray = array(

'coolid' => array(
    'id' => 'coolid',
    'tag' => '{my:coolid}', 
    'label' => __( 'coolid', 'my_plugin' ),
    'callback' => 'coolid'
  ));

'emailaddress' => array(
    'id' => 'foo',
    'tag' => '{my:emailddress}', 
    'label' => __( 'emailaddress', 'my_plugin' ),
    'callback' => 'emailaddress'
  ));
```

all help appreciated, ive tried this foreach.. but no luck

```
foreach($data['@attributes'] as $key) {    
   $key = array(
    'id' =>  $key,
    'tag' => '{my:'.$key.'}', 
    'label' => __( $key, 'my_plugin' ),
    'callback' => $key
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$desiredArray = array();
foreach($data['@attributes'] as $key => $value) {    
   $desiredArray[$key] = array(
      'id' =>  $key,
      'tag' => '{my:'.$key.'}', 
      'label' => __( $key, 'my_plugin' ),
      'callback' => $key
   );
}
```

[Check foreach syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)